# Strimzi Kafka Connect how to mount PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I am deploying KafkaConnect using Custom Resource. I would like to mount to Kafka Connect cluster PersistentVolumeClaim. The idea is that another application responsible for file transfer will place there file that will be picked up by kafka connector.

I checked KafkaConnect resource config docs and it seems that I cannot simply add the volume to the Pod.
My understanding is that if I will patch the Pod strimzi-operator will recognise the modification and on the next reconciliation will overwrite it.

Would anyone have an idea how can I still use KafkaConnect CR and mount the pvc volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Strimzi. There is an enhancement issue for this (https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/2571) but nobody implemented it yet.

I wonder if for the use-case you describe something like running the Kafka Connect as a sidecar would make more sense. You could then share the storage directly without any networking etc. (This is not something supported by Strimzi, But Kafka Connect itself can of course be used like this)